# Ansible keeps wanting to be root

Tags: ansible

I'm a beginner with Ansible, and I need to run some basic tasks on a remote server.

The procedure is as follows:

- I log as some user (osadmin)
- I run `su -` to become root
- I then do the tasks I need to.

So, I wrote my playbook as follows:

```
---
- hosts: qualif
  vars:
    - ansible_user: osadmin
    - ansible_password: H1g2.D6#
  tasks:
    - name: Copy stuff from here to over there
      copy:
       src: /home/osadmin/file.txt
       dest: /home/osadmin/file-changed.txt
       owner: osadmin
       group: osadmin
       mode: 0777
```

Also, I have the following in vars/main.yml:

```
ansible_user: osadmin
ansible_password: password1
ansible_become_password: password2
[ some other values ]
```

However, when running my tasks, Ansible / the hosts returns me the following:

> "Incorrect sudo password"

I then changed my tasks so that instead of becoming sudo and copy the file in some place my osadmin doesn't have access, I just copy the file on `/home/osadmin`. So, theorically, no need to become sudo for just a simple copy.
The problem now is that not only it keeps saying "wrong sudo password", but if I remove it, Ansible asks for it.

I then decided to run the command and added `-vvv` at the end, and it showed me the following:

> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: osadmin
>
> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o User=osadmin -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/osadmin/.ansible/cp/b9489e2193 -tt HOST-ADDRESS '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n -u
>
> root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-ewujwywrqhcqfdrkaglvrouhmuiefwlj; /usr/bin/python /home/osadmin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1550076004.1888492-11284794413477/AnsiballZ_setup.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
>
> (1, b'sudo: a password is required\r\n', b'Shared connection to HOST-ADDRESS closed.\r\n')

As you can see, it somehow uses root, while I never told him to.

Does anyone know why Ansible keeps trying to be sudo, and how can I disable this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried `become: false`?

Comment: Check group_vars and host_vars in inventory and playbook directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between 'su' and 'sudo'. If you have 'su' access, that means, that you can log as root (may be not, but it looks like). Use `ansible_ssh_user=root`, `ansible_password=password2`.

If this doesn't work, try to configure sudo on a server. You should be able to run `sudo whoami` and to get answer `root`. After that your code should run.

One more thing: you are using 'copy' module incorrectly. It uses `src` as path on *local* machine (where ansible is run), and `dst` as path on remote machine.

Comment: I finally ended by configuring my user so that he has sudo privileges. I no longer have problems, thanks :)